# longtabu X-columns break with xcolor

Tags: pdftex, color, windows, longtabu

Hello I have a few longtabu's in a document, some of those use xcolor to slightly alternate the row color. I have been using something similar as below for more than a year now, but updating my texlive distribution breaks it (on Windows). It spews alot of the following at me, refering to the line containing `\end{longtabu}`

```
Missing } inserted. \end{longtabu}
Missing \cr inserted. \end{longtabu}
Misplaced \cr. \end{longtabu}
...
```

The minimal example:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,height=24cm,top=2.5cm,width=16cm,left=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}  % removing this line helps
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{tabu}

\begin{document}
  \begin{longtabu} to \textwidth{XX}  % changing to l-columns works too
    This is a & Test! \\
    Using xcolor together with X-columns & doesn't compile.\\
    This happens on recent windows distributions of & texlive. \\
  \end{longtabu}
\end{document}
```

It works fine on my older Windows texlive installation and it works fine on a recent texlive distribution on ArchLinux. I tested everything on (scheme-full) installations. I also rebuilt the xcolor and tabu packages.

The problem seems to occur with the `color`-package as well.

**TLDR**; longtabu and xcolor/color don't work together on recent Windows texlive (13th January 2019).

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Thank you! That is exactly my problem! I did not find it even after hours of searching.

Comment: hm, it is listed on the right side of your question, as last of the similar question :-) after while you will have more practice how to find similar problems here on site ...